# Cannot assign "'somedata'": "otherdatal" must be a "" instance.`

Tags: python, django, django-models, instance

Is it possible to insert the session value to the foreign key?

I have 2 models

```
class candidate(models.Model):
    fname=models.CharField("First name ",max_length=20,default="")
    lname=models.CharField("Last name ",max_length=20,default="")
    email=models.EmailField("Email ",max_length=254,primary_key=True)
    password=models.CharField("Password ",max_length=100,default="")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email #self.fname+" " +self.lname

class canDetails(models.Model):
    candEmail=models.ForeignKey(candidate,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location=models.CharField("location ",max_length=30)
    role=models.CharField("role ",max_length=20)
    cv=models.FileField(upload_to="media/canDetails/")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.candEmail
```

I am taking the email from above model as a session and trying to put this session value to the foreign key field of the other model, but here I am getting an error like:

> Cannot assign "'cb@gmail.com'": "canDetails.candEmail" must be a "candidate" instance.

I am trying to get all the details from candidate model and candDetails model at once thats why i using pf and fk here,so is it the right way i am following...?
how can i deal with this ? any suggestions pls.?

Answer (score 0):

The model `canDetails` needs to know to which `candidate` it belongs, so the `Foreingkey` field needs to be an `candidate` instance (in the database the PK value is stored). I strongly suggest, just like the Django docs also suggest, naming the field `candidate` and capitalizing the model names, for more clarity.

```
class Candidate(models.Model):
    ...

class CanDetails(models.Model):
    candidate = models.ForeignKey(Candidate, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

If you only have the email, then you can use that to look up which `Candidate` it belongs to, fetch that instance and assign it to the `CanDetails`. For example:

```
try:
    the_candidate = Candidate.objects.get(email='cb@gmail.com')
except (Candidate.DoesNotExist, Candidate.MultipleObjectsReturned):
    # raise error or exit
    return

det = CanDetails()
det.candidate = the_candidate
...
det.save()
```